# Unable to properly use custom javascript files in a test suite

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an odd issue trying to implement the Page Object patterns into my test suite using selenium-webdriver and node.

I am able to use the the first page object pageObject/admin/login/index.js. This file has selectors and methods that fills out the forms on the signin page allowing a user to log themselves in. After they login the next page object fails completely. The next step should simply verify that the users name is found on the page (using the appropriate selectors and getText method).

Here is my testing suite:

```
var driver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var chai = require('chai');
var sinon = require('sinon');
var sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
var expect = chai.expect;
var should = chai.should;
var config = require('../../../../variables');
var AdminPage = require('../../../../pageObject/admin/login/index.js');
var HeaderProfile = require('../../../../pageObject/admin/login/common/headerProfile/index.js');

chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'));
chai.use(sinonChai);

describe('Webdriver - Admin Tests - User Alice', function() {
  var adminVar = process.env.envVar;
  var login = config[adminVar].adminLogin;
  var user = config[adminVar].role.adminUser.name;
  var email = config[adminVar].role.adminUser.email;
  var pw = config[adminVar].role.adminUser.password;
  before(function() {
    this.timeout(50000);
    this.driver = new driver.Builder().withCapabilities(driver.Capabilities.firefox()).build();
    this.driver.get(login);
    var adminPage = new AdminPage(this.driver);

    adminPage.fillEmail(email);
    adminPage.fillPassword(pw);
    adminPage.signin();

    return this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(250);
  });

  after(function() {
    return this.driver.quit();
  });

  describe('would like to', function() {
    it('verify they have global access', function() {
      this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(500);

      var headerProfile = new HeaderProfile(this.driver);

      return expect(headerProfile.getName()).to.eventually.equal(user);
    });
  });

});
```

Here are my Page Objects for login:

```
/*jslint node: true */
"use strict";
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var config = require('../../../variables.json');

var adminVar = process.env.envVar;
var login = config[adminVar].adminLogin;
var user = config[adminVar].role.adminUser.name;
var email = config[adminVar].role.adminUser.email;
var pw = config[adminVar].role.adminUser.password;


class AdminPage {
  constructor(driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000);

    this.emailField = this.driver.findElement({
      css: 'input[name="email"]'
    });

    this.passwordField = this.driver.findElement({
      css: 'input[name="password"]'
    });

    this.loginButton = this.driver.findElement({
      css: 'button[type="submit"]'
    });
  }

  fillEmail(email) {
    this.emailField.sendKeys(email);
  }

  fillPassword(password) {
    this.passwordField.sendKeys(password);
  }

  signin() {
    this.loginButton.click();
  }
}

module.exports = AdminPage;
```

and the Page Object for headerProfile:

```
/*jslint node: true */
"use strict";
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');


class HeaderProfile {
  constructor(driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000);

    this.profileName = this.driver.findElement({
      css: '#app > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1)'
    });

    this.profileMenu = this.driver.findElement({
      css: '#app > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > button'
    });

    this.profileOrg = this.driver.findElement({
      css: 'div.secondaryText'
    });
  }

  getName() {
    this.profileName.getText();
  }

  clickMenu() {
    this.profileMenu.click();
  }
}

module.exports = HeaderProfile;
```

Using this I get the following errors when running the code:

```
1) Webdriver - PC6 - Admin Tests - User Alice would like to verify they have global access:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
      at assertIsAboutPromise (node_modules/chai-as-promised/lib/chai-as-promised.js:47:38)
      at null.<anonymous> (node_modules/chai-as-promised/lib/chai-as-promised.js:65:17)
      at addProperty (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/addProperty.js:42:29)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/admin/dashboard/adminUser/pdvi-2377.js:51:48)

2) Webdriver - PC6 - Admin Tests - User Alice "after all" hook:
   Uncaught Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:49665
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:174:16)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:265:9)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1253:8)
From: Task: WebDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000)
    at webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:362:15)
    at webdriver.WebDriver.Timeouts.implicitlyWait (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:1352:23)
    at Context.<anonymous> (test/admin/dashboard/adminUser/pdvi-2377.js:57:39)
```

I thought about not using chai-as-promised and using normal chai expects to help my problem by changing my last describe statement to:

```
describe('would like to', function() {
  it('verify they have global access', function() {
    this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(500);

    var headerProfile = new HeaderProfile(this.driver);

    return expect(headerProfile.getName()).to.equal(user);
  });
});
```

but it yields this error:

```
1) Webdriver - PC6 - Admin Tests - User Alice would like to verify they have global access:
   AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 'John Doe'
    at Context.<anonymous> (test/admin/dashboard/adminUser/pdvi-2377.js:51:49)

2) Webdriver - PC6 - Admin Tests - User Alice "after all" hook:
   Uncaught Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:57292
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:174:16)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:265:9)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1253:8)
From: Task: WebDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000)
    at webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:362:15)
    at webdriver.WebDriver.Timeouts.implicitlyWait (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:1352:23)
    at Context.<anonymous> (test/admin/dashboard/adminUser/pdvi-2377.js:57:39)
```

However if I just place the selector into my describe statement like the following:

```
describe('would like to', function() {
  it('verify they have global access', function() {
    this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(500);

    var userName = this.driver.findElement({
      css: '#app > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1)'
    }).getText();

    return expect(userName).to.eventually.equal(user);
  });
});
```

my code is able to run successfully and all tests pass with zero errors.

This leads me to believe that I may not be properly loading my page objects correctly or maybe there is possibly some timing issue with selenium-webdriver? My method is clearly returns the text in a select as undefined

If I am able to use the selector directly in my it statement doesn't this mean that I am not properly using my selectors correctly in my headerProfile/index.js page object? If they are coming up undefined then the issue should be somewhere in the page object correct?

I'm not too sure if this problem is a selenium-webdriver or vanilla javascript issue.

My original purpose of using page objects is to have a central location for the selectors without having to change selectors in every test file but only change the selectors in a central location. Perhaps there is a better way to accomplish this?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that the functions in the PageObjects do not return anything. The default return value is 'undefined'.

Have you tried:

```
getName() {
    return this.profileName.getText();
}
```

This should return the promise from getText() which will have the .then method. Hopefully that clears up the "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" error.

Comment: uhhh. I feel so foolish. This helped resolved my issue and I was able to blow through a bunch of tickets as a result! Thank you.